# How to change app open ad background color?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, admob

I have placed the native ads in some app's screens, but whenever app come to foreground, the app open ad is open with transparent background and showing over native ads, So now i have to give background color to app open ad, so how to give background color to app open ad ?
Here is some code of the application.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === 'active'
      ) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (appOpenAdState.canShowAppOpenAd && appOpenAd.loaded) {
            appOpenAd.show();
          } else {
            appOpenAdState.canShowAppOpenAd = true;
            appOpenAd.load();
          }
        }, 500);
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, [appOpenAdState.canShowAppOpenAd]);
```

When application come to foreground then app open ad is showing with a transparent background. I want to change the color from transparent to black or some other color.

Comment: Please include some code snippet or what you have used in react-native for showing ad.

Comment: I m using react-native-admob/admob library, and there is no issue there, But I want to remove transparent background from app open ads and want to add some another background color to hide native ads behind it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cannot customise the `AppOpenAd`, however, you can create a blank activity with dark background & use that as a splash screen only when an AppOpenAd is available/loaded & then navigate to your MainActivity when it is dismissed.

Comment: I created as you said but that is not acceptable in my case,
But thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this problem I have add the below code to android manifest file.

first create a file theme.xml and copy this code.

```
<resources>
 <style name="AdTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

after this just ad these lines to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AdTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
/>
```

this is just for android . for iOS I am still searching.